# Additional component in fenix makeRustPlatform

Tags: rust, nix

I'm writing a Nix derivation to compute code coverage in CI, and I've got the following definition for my Rust platform in my Flake's output:

```hs
{
  # ...
  rust = pkgs.makeRustPlatform {
    inherit (fenix.packages.x86_64-linux.complete) cargo rustc;
  }
  # ...
}
```

The above relies on the flake inputs following:

```hs
{
  inputs.fenix.url = "github:nix-community/fenix";
  inputs.fenix.inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
}
```

However, I get an error suggesting that a required component for code coverage computation isn't installed, specifically `llvm-tools-preview`. How can I make sure that it's available in my rustPlatform?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a component to the toolchain by specifying a `rust-toolchain.toml` in my crate root:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2021-10-29"
components = [ "llvm-tools-preview" ]
profile = "minimal"
```

I deferred handling to a reference to this file in my flake.nix, rather than relying on the given presets:

```hs
rust = let toolchain = fenix.packages.x86_64-linux.fromToolchainFile {
      file = ./rust-toolchain.toml;
      sha256 = pkgs.lib.fakeSha256;
    };
  in pkgs.makeRustPlatform {
    rustc = toolchain;
    cargo = toolchain;
  };
```